# K-means on a m x n matrix having strings and numeric data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to perform K means clustering in MATLAB on a mxn matrix containing both string and numeric data and then display it. How do i perform it.

Answer (score 0):

To cluster a matrix of numeric data you can use the following.

idx = kmeans(X,k)

performs k-means clustering to partition the observations of the n-by-p data matrix X into k clusters, and returns an n-by-1 vector (idx) containing cluster indices of each observation. Rows of X correspond to points and columns correspond to variables.

More info: http://mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Clustering both numeric and strings is generally not possible..

Can you post (a sample of) your matrix?

Comment: Quoting the documentation is not necessarily useful.  The OP can do that him or herself.  You are also asking for clarification.  That should be reserved as a comment, but you don't have enough reputation to do that.  Instead, actually write answers that answer the question, not quoting documentation or asking for clarification.